# How use IsFullScreenChanged and isFullScreen on Media Player Framework Windows phone 8.0/8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

When create a event for IsFullScreenChanged for example:

```
player.IsFullScreenChanged += player_IsFullScreenChanged();
```

The parameter of the function are:

```
private void player_IsFullScreenChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool> e)
{
  MediaElement mediaPlayer = (MediaElement) sender
  /*Wrong line: */
  player.IsFullScreen = true;
}
```

This function it's called when the **full screen button** is clicked.
Then there is an attribute: "IsFullScreen" which when set to true, running automate the full screen.
The question is: how to use the parameter of the function "player_IsFullScreenChanged" to set (MediaElement).isFullScreen = true?

I do not know for what reason this function does crash the program.
Thank you!

Comment: Where's the exception that crashes the app?  If I had to guess, you're getting a StackOverflow, because you're changing `IsFullscreen` in the event handler that fires every time `IsFullscreen` changes.  Don't do that.

Comment: No exceptions, could you explain more precisely? Because I think you're right ...

Comment: Stack trace: IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>IsFullscreen changes>The event fires>You change IsFullscreen>StackOverflowException

Comment: Ok clear, I imagine that this thing was happening. The problem is that I have no idea how to get out!

Comment: Don't change IsFullscreen in the IsFullscreenChanged event.  The real question is why you are doing this, as it makes no sense to change the value in the event handler.  You need to [edit] and explain your goals.

Comment: Ok, my problem is that I want to achieve a full screen when a user clicks on the "full screen" just that I have no idea what function to use to do this. The only function that does something when that button is pressed is "player_IsFullScreenChanged" but that for obvious reasons can not be used.

Comment: So, you're saying IsFullscreen can be `true` yet the element isn't fullscreen?

Comment: I'm not saying that I need to become fullscreen when I click the button

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what you *are* saying

Comment: I understand, basically I need that when I click on a button, the player steps from normal to full screen.

Comment: It seems to me that the control should be able to handle becoming fullscreen without any intervention on your part.  Have you tried removing your event handler?

Comment: Already tried, and like you, for me seems very strange. Now we are at the same point. I run out of ideas

Comment: This idea is incorrect.  I'm not familiar with the media element, nor with wp enough to help you with this situation, unfortunately.  Can you create a simple app with a single media element and see how it behaves?  You might have something else preventing the element from going fullscreen...